# Prolog Program to output the last and the pre-last element of a list

Tags: prolog

I need something like this last_And_prelast([5,a,d,2],A,B) that outputs A=d and B=2

thanks

Comment: Do you have some code that you've attempted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem was already solved here: [How to get the 2 last values from a list in recursion and in tail-recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473204/how-to-get-the-2-last-values-from-a-list-in-recursion-and-in-tail-recursion)

Use this

```
last2_2([_|T],X,Y) :- last2_2(T,X,Y).
```

or this

```
last2_2([_,_|T],Y,Z):-last2_2(T,Y,Z).
last2_2([_,A,B],A,B).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using builtins, as suggested by @CappeliC:

```
last2( Xs , A , B ) :- append(_,[A,B],Xs) .
```

or even

```
last2( Xs , A , B ) :- reverse(Xs,[B,A|_]) .
```

Or you could try rolling your own

```
last2( [A,B]  , A , B ) .
last2( [_|Xs] , A , B ) :- last2(Xs,A,B) .
```

There's more than one way to do it.